# Looking for an ajax image viewer that work with php or convert one from asp to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I am looking for a javascript(better if based on jquery) Ajax image viewer with zoom feature that I can work on with php.

The best thing I found close to what I need was this great script:

[thinDoc](http://www.atalasoft.com/31apps/ThinDoc/About.aspx)

You can view a demo here:
http://www.atalasoft.com/31apps/ThinDoc/

The problem with this script that it works only with asp not php. So if anybody can convert it to php that would be great. Or find a similar thing that I can use with php.

Comment: No, we're not going to rewrite an entire script for you. That's not how this site works.

Comment: lol, i don't know asp and i didn't ask anybody to write anything for me. i am just asking if somebody came across this before and he is willing to help. thanks for your help anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their documentation, you can just use their service without any server-side programming. Just embed your link to your pdf:

> > http://www.atalasoft.com/31apps/thindoc/?url=

### Example:

For the pdf: http://lerdorf.com/veracruz.pdf

> > http://www.atalasoft.com/31apps/thindoc/?url=http://lerdorf.com/veracruz.pdf

It also works with images:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Gardiners_Island_Windmill.jpg
becomes:

> > http://www.atalasoft.com/31apps/thindoc/?url=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Gardiners_Island_Windmill.jpg

Comment: thanks, but i need to manipulate the code behind the javascript(the asp code). if i just can find a similar script in jquery. that will be helpful.